# Comparing two files with simple answears, summing them up with no output to console

Tags: linux, bash, comparison, diff

I have two files as atributes in my script with ten lines in each. They contain simple answers: YES or NO. I need to compare those two files and get number of good answers and bad answers. I need to have them in separate variables.
I have tried :

`diff <(nl $1) <(nl $2) | grep -E '<' | wc -l`

and i get number of bad aswers, but i want it to be in some variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're no good at describing what you want to achieve or the command doesn't do what you think it does.

Anyway - to store the output in a variable just do:

```
variable=$(diff <(nl $1) <(nl $2) | grep -E '<' | wc -l)
```